# Values of $p$ for an improper integral to converge

Tags: improper-integrals

I am trying to find values of $p \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} x^p\sin(e^x)$ converges.  All I have managed doing is using reduction formulas but I couldn't reach a result. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near $+\infty$ one has by partial integration
\begin{equation}
\int x^p \sin(e^x) d x = -x^p e^{-x} \cos(e^x) + \int(p x^{p-1}-x^p)e^{-x}\cos(e^x) d x
\end{equation}
which clearly converges for all $p\in {\mathbb R}$

Near $0$, we have $x^p \sin(e^x) \sim x^p \sin(1)$ which converges iff $p> -1$

Comment: Where does the $e^{-x}$ comes from ?

Comment: @EDX I write $x^p \sin(e^x) = x^p e^{-x} e^x \sin(e^x)$ because I want to use that $e^x \sin(e^x) = (-\cos(e^x))'$

Comment: Ok nice thanks :)